# .NET Portable Class Library Profiles Strategy

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, portable-class-library

I'm developing an open-source SQL database system on .NET ([DeveelDB](https://github.com/deveel/deveeldb)), almost an hobbistic project, and I'm planning to create a portable library to support mobile contexts.

The project uses some external libraries that it merges in ([DryIoC](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc), [Deveel.Math](https://github.com/deveel/deveel-math) and others), but some will be stripped out from the portable version (eg. [ANTLRv4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4)).

I am now facing a strategic problem about this, since I've explored the various profiles for Portable Class Library model ([like in this post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html), even if a bit out of date), and it seems I should produce many versions of of the library for each profile.

The profile reference is also problematic when it comes to libraries the project is dependent from (eg. [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage)), that limit much the options.
With this regard, I will also have to make a release of [Deveel.Math](https://github.com/deveel/deveel-math) (that I also develop) to be compatible with the PCL model I want to use in [DeveelDB](https://github.com/deveel/deveeldb)

I was wondering if anyone who has had similar issues has any tips on how to make a single release that is comprehensive of the widest range of audiences in this regard.

Thank you for your kind answers and suggestions.

Comment: Hmya, this quickly stops being a hobby when you want to support *everything*.  Only support the ones you can/want to actually test.  It is open source, somebody else can add another platform if they need it.

Comment: It's a good point and probably I will follow this path, starting with a sort of `deveeldb.pcl.profile1.csproj` and making configurations after that.

Comment: May be look ahead to support [Netstandard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library). Otherwise it is hard. I did use proxy projects with linked source files targeting specific profiles. The sufficient profiles are two: 259 and 328. For the rest, accept PRs.